# Bootstrap certain buttons are not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When hovering my social buttons the hyperlink appears and the link can be launched by right clicking and choosing an option, but not on a single click. They were built differently in html to help my troubleshooting but I can't get either of them to send me to the respective social pages. They are located in the 4 wide column in the social row. I went a little crazy nesting columns to keep everything centered. Any help is appreciated.

test site can be found here: http://www.tedrmoke.com/cjs

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
                    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="sawmill.html">Sawmill</a></li>
                            <li><a href="lumber">Purchase</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </nav>
    <!-- Jumbotron -->
            <div class="row text-center jumbo">
                <h1>Hello! We are <br/><span>CJ Sawmill &amp; Lumber</span></h1>
                <h3>We specialize in coming to you and cutting your lumber in the central NJ area. We also have a selection of quality cured cuts available for purchase.</h3>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
                 <div class="col-xs-8 social">
                 <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="collapse-group"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Contact Us.</a>
            <form class="collapse" name="contactform" method="post" action="http://www.cjsawmill-lumber.com/send_form_email.php">
                <table class"col-lg-12 text-left" >
                    ...
                </table>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div> <!-- row -->
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="http://www.twitter.com/cjsawmill"><div class="btn btn-default twi_btn"></div></a>
                <a class="btn btn-default fb_btn" href="http://www.facebook.com/cjsawmill"></a>
            </div>
            </div> <!-- col-6 button row -->
            <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
            </div> <!-- button row -->
            </div>
        </div> <!-- container -->
   </div> <!-- end jumbotron -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in your javascript :

```
// JavaScript Document

$('.row .btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var $collapse = $this.closest('.collapse-group').find('.collapse');
    $collapse.collapse('toggle');
});
```

, you are preventing the default event whenever an element with class `btn` is clicked inside an element of class `row`.

Notice in your HTML, that both your hyperlinks and divs for facebook and twitter respectively are of the class `btn` due to which, whenever they are clicked, the default event (that is redirecting to their `href`) is prevented which is why the links dont work on a single click, but they do work on right click, since the right click only uses the href attribute to redirect you to the new link.

Try removing the `e.preventDefault();` from being applied to your hyperlinks or divs inside hyperlinks and then the social buttons should work just fine on a single left click as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript says

```
$('.row .btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    # . . .
});
```

So I would target that to just the specific 'Contact Us' button, not all butons.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap can be restrictive in a way that won't let you wrap your button in an a tag. Like you could in regular html. Here is a solution that I used to a similar issue I had, structure you a tag like this and you should still get a button that functions.Place in your class names of course.

```
<a class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></a>
```